# Limit of a function $x f(x) $ as $x$ tends to infinity if $f(x) \searrow 0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Suppose $f(x)$ is a positive decreasing function such that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$ and such $\forall x: 0 < f(x) < 1/x $. Then obviously also $\forall x: 0 < xf(x) < 1 $.

Does $\lim_{x \to \infty} xf(x)$ necessarily exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it may not exist. For example, if we let
$$
f(x) = \frac1{2^{n+1}}\ \  \text{ for } 2^n\le x<2^{n+1},
$$ then $f$ satisfies every given condition. However, $$
xf(x) = \frac{x}{2^{n+1}}\ \  \text{ for } 2^n\le x<2^{n+1}
$$ oscillates between $\frac12$ and $1$ infinitely often. Thus there is no $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}xf(x)$.

Note: As @TonyK pointed out in his comment, we can make $f$ continuous by smoothing $f$ near discontinuities at $x=2^{n}$'s, while retaining property that $\not\exists \lim\limits_{x\to\infty}xf(x)$. Also, we can make $f$ strictly decreasing, for example, by multiplying $\frac1{\sqrt{x/2^n}}.$

Comment: Note to the OP: this function is not continuous, but it can be made continuous by judicious smoothing around the points $x=2^n$, while retaining the property that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}xf(x)$ doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you both! Could you think of any assumption on $f$ to guarantee the limit existence then?

Comment: @Vojtěch Umm ... Things like $\int_0^\infty f(x)\mathrm dx <\infty$ guarantees $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} xf(x) = 0$. Or I guess that $\frac{1}{\log x}\int_0^x f(t)\mathrm dt \xrightarrow{x\to\infty} c$ with some additional conditions would work.